# VsCode Extension API to get GitHub repository owner

Tags: git, github, vscode-extensions

I'm working on VSCode extension and need to get Github repository owner.

For example, for this repository https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/ Microsoft is repository owner.

Could you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try already? Where are you stuck? You can call the REST API from GitHub to load the repo info, which also contains the repo owner. See their docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-repository

Comment: Thanks for reply @RobBos. I tried to use VSCode Git API to get repo information. But it's not working for me. I posted another question here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75019378/how-to-get-vscode-git-api-repository-information

Don't sure maybe it's better to use Octokit library or another approach...